# Connection to Excel in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

how to connect C# with Excel...by using some Interop services

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of the question you posted 30 minutes earlier?

Answer (score 1):

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

// Connect to Excel
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
// Do this if you want to see Excel 
excelApp.Visible = true;
// Open the spreadsheet
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open("MyFile.xls"
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
// Get the collection of worksheets
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets sheets = workbook.Worksheets;
for (sheet = 1; sheet <= sheets.Count; sheet++)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(sheet);
    // Do something with the worksheet
    worksheet.Activate(); // do this if you have Excel visible so you can see what you're doing
}
// Close the workbook
excelApp.Workbooks.Close();
// Close Excel
excelApp.Application.Quit();
```

Comment: @Chris: Look at Reddy's earlier question. Looks like he does not have Excel installed on his system. In that case, of course, he cannot use Interop.

Comment: Aha, well, yes, that will make it difficult to use Excel Interop then... however, the question explicitly says "using some Interop services". Nevermind, maybe this will be helpful to someone that does have Excel installed.